# How to speed up graph generation (NetworkX)

Tags: python, graph, bigdata, networkx

I’ve got new dataset with big graph (111000 nodes and 130000 connections) i need to get good looking coordinates of each node and put it back to csv.

now i am using

```
networkx.spring_layout(G)
```

But it takes over 60 minutes and still no result.

Do you know better way (even another lib or language) to deal with my problem?

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score 1):

Python is slow.  For problems of this size ( > 10,000 nodes ) you need a compiled language.  I use C++ for this sort of thing.  C++ can be up to 50 times faster than python.

Note that the networkx  library is written in C++.  It is not the library that is at fault, but the rest of your python code.  You should run timing test to confirm this.

You should always run timing tests BEFORE looking for optimizations, so you know where to look.

Performance example:

Run time for running the Dijkstra algorithm to find the cheapest paths from one randomly selected vertex to every other vertex on large graphs downloaded from https://dyngraphlab.github.io/.  Longest result from 3 runs using the graphex C++ application. ( https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/Costs#performance)

| Vertex Count | Edge Count | Run time ( secs ) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10,000 | 50,000 | 0.3 |
| 145,000 | 2,200,000 | 40 |